# How to catch event for email either sent or discarded, using below code

Tags: java, android, email, events, android-intent

How to catch event for email either sent or discarded, using below code.

```
String mailId = "mygmailid@gmail.com";
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("mailto", mailId,     null));
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Subject");
String body = "Email body text";
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body text here");
emailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm",     "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
startActivity(emailIntent);
try {
    startActivityForResult(emailIntent, 1);
} 
catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(dashboardActivity, "There is no gmail client installed.",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use `ACTION_SENDTO`, not `ACTION_VIEW`, as there is no requirement for any email client to support sending an email via a `mailto:` `Uri` and `ACTION_VIEW`.

> How to catch event for email either sent or discarded

There is no such event, for either case, as part of the `ACTION_SENDTO` protocol (let alone `ACTION_VIEW`). There is no requirement or standard means for a third-party email client to tell you what happened to the email.